# INSERTING TOTALS IN A SINGLE TABLE

Tags: sql

I have some data from the general ledger in a table called "`GL Table`"  - `Country`, `Account` and `Amount`.  I am trying to SUM the amount field based on certain accounts in the account field, then insert the SUM as "Revised Income" for each country at the bottom of the same table in the same fields (`Country, Account, Amount`).  I keep running into roadblocks and i'm wondering if I am supposed to create another table for this instead of keeping it in the same table.

Here's what I came up with but it is not working.

```
SELECT  COUNTRY, 
        AMOUNT 
FROM    GL_TABLE
WHERE   AMOUNT =  (
          SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM GL_TABLE
          WHERE  ACCOUNT IN 'PTBI' OR 
                 ACCOUNT IN 'MLS_ENT' OR 
                 ACCOUNT IN 'VAL_ALLOW' OR 
                 ACCOUNT IN 'RSC_DEV'
          GROUP BY COUNTRY);
```

Comment: You're going to insert it into the same table?  Does the account name change or something?  How do you tell the rows apart?

Comment: Please show some example data and desired results. I'm not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: COUNTRY,ACCOUNT,AMOUNT
USA,PTBI,1
USA,MLS_ENT,1
USA,RSC_DEV,1
USA,VAL_ALLOW,1
USA,TPV,1

Comment: i want to add up the first four rows and call it USA,REVISED_INCOME,4.  and do it for every country in the table.

Comment: This worked  INSERT INTO GL_TABLE

SELECT COUNTRY, 'TAX_INC' AS ACCOUNT, SUM(AMOUNT) FROM GL_TABLE
WHERE ACCOUNT IN ('PTBI','MLS_ENT','VAL_ALLOW','RSC_DEV')
GROUP BY COUNTRY;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT), COUNTRY FROM GL_TABLE WHERE ACCOUNT IN 'PTBI' OR ACCOUNT IN 'MLS_ENT' OR ACCOUNT IN 'VAL_ALLOW' OR ACCOUNT IN 'RSC_DEV' GROUP BY COUNTRY
```

if you want to find the sum of all accounts for a country, or if you want it broken down by account by country

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT), COUNTRY, ACCOUNT FROM GL_TABLE WHERE ACCOUNT IN 'PTBI' OR ACCOUNT IN 'MLS_ENT' OR ACCOUNT IN 'VAL_ALLOW' OR ACCOUNT IN 'RSC_DEV' GROUP BY COUNTRY, ACCOUNT
```

As for whether to insert it back into the same table I would say for db normalization that would be a bad idea.  If you can calculate it, it would be better to just run a query and if the query is too long to run then it may be appropriate to run the query and populate a separate table just as long as the users know that it is a snapshot in time rather than real-time data.

Comment: some context around what I am doing - i am trying to learn more about calculating base data in the fact table itself vs. spinning off a dimension table and doing the aggregation there.  I have a bunch of financial data i want to add, subtract, multiply and divide and I want to get a sense for how difficult it is to actually write the SQL query.  I am bringing in the balance for these accounts by country and then do simple arithmetic on the balances in the code and then writing the value back to the table as a new account.

Answer (score 1):

your question is really unclear....

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0bc3/1/0

```
create table GL_Table (
   Country  varchar(20), 
   Account  varchar(20), 
   Amount   float
);

insert into GL_Table values ('USA','PTBI',100); 
insert into GL_Table values ('USA','PTBI',100); 
insert into GL_Table values ('USA','PTBI',100); 

insert into GL_Table values ('USA','MLS_ENT',101);  

insert into GL_Table values ('USA','RSC_DEV',102);   
insert into GL_Table values ('USA','RSC_DEV',102);  

insert into GL_Table values ('USA','NOTHING',777);   
insert into GL_Table values ('USA','NOTHING',777);
```

So the data would now be:

```
COUNTRY      ACCOUNT          AMOUNT
USA          PTBI             100
USA          PTBI             100
USA          PTBI             100
USA          MLS_ENT          101
USA          RSC_DEV          102
USA          RSC_DEV          102
USA          NOTHING          777
USA          NOTHING          777
```

Then the query to add `SUM` rows of only certain things would be like:

```
INSERT INTO GL_TABLE 

      SELECT  COUNTRY, 
              concat('SUM OF ', ACCOUNT) as NEW_ACCT_NAME, 
              SUM(AMOUNT) as SUM_ACCOUNT

      FROM    GL_TABLE

      WHERE   ACCOUNT IN ('PTBI', 'MLS_ENT','VAL_ALLOW','RSC_DEV')

      GROUP   BY COUNTRY, ACCOUNT;
```

And now the data would be (`select * from gl_table`):

```
COUNTRY      ACCOUNT          AMOUNT
USA          PTBI             100
USA          PTBI             100
USA          PTBI             100
USA          MLS_ENT          101
USA          RSC_DEV          102
USA          RSC_DEV          102
USA          NOTHING          777
USA          NOTHING          777
USA          SUM OF MLS_ENT   101
USA          SUM OF PTBI      300
USA          SUM OF RSC_DEV   204
```

---

looked at your query again and it looks like you want a country sum?  dunno... (not much would change)

```
INSERT INTO GL_TABLE 

      SELECT  COUNTRY, 
              concat('SUM FOR ', COUNTRY) as NEW_ACCT_NAME, 
              SUM(AMOUNT) as SUM_ACCOUNT

      FROM    GL_TABLE

      WHERE   ACCOUNT IN ('PTBI', 'MLS_ENT','VAL_ALLOW','RSC_DEV')

      GROUP   BY COUNTRY;
```

so the data would end up being...

```
COUNTRY      ACCOUNT          AMOUNT
USA          PTBI             100
USA          PTBI             100
USA          PTBI             100
USA          MLS_ENT          101
USA          RSC_DEV          102
USA          RSC_DEV          102
USA          NOTHING          777
USA          NOTHING          777
USA          SUM FOR USA      605
```